# Why is my dropdown navbar disappearing after I try to fix it?

Tags: html, css

My navbar is disappearing every time I try the position:fixed. I've gone through similar questions and I still can't figure it out. For that matter, the only position that is working is the position:static, all the other ones will mess up the dropdown bar or just won't show up. I'm basically just trying to make a sticky header.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width:100%;
  height: 74px;

}

/* Style the header links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;


}

/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
.navbar a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #002873;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}

.navbar-icon {
  float: right;
  padding: 1px;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: none;
  }
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;

}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar">
  <a href="home.html" class="title" style="font-weight:bolder; font-size:40px; color:#002873" > ExhibitLab </a>
  <div class="navbar-right">

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> <a href="about.html">About</a> </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="history.html">History</a>
        <a href="#timeline">Timeline</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> <a href="#publication">Publication</a> </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#report">Report</a>
        <a href="#sources">Additional Sources</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> <a href="#research">Research</a> </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#thesis">Thesis</a>
        <a href="#context">Context</a>
        <a href="#imp">Global Implications</a>
        <a href="#proof">Mathematical Proof</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> <a href="#model">Model</a> </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#2D">2D Model</a>
        <a href="#sketchup">SketchUp Model</a>
        <a href="#econmodek">Economic Model</a>
        <a href="#enviromodel">Environmental Model</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> <a href="#exhibit">Exhibit</a> </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#preview">Preview</a>
        <a href="#location">Location</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> <a href="#media">Media</a></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> <a href="#team">Team</a></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#prof">Leading Professor</a>
        <a href="#phd">PhD Students</a>
        <a href="#grad">Grad Researchers</a>
        <a href="#undergrad">Undergrad Researchers</a>
        <a href="#extra">Additional Support</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "navbar-icon">
      <a href="#contact" class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px"> mail_outline </a>
      <a href="#search" class="material-icons" style="font-size:20px" >search</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap provides a class for fixing your navbar at the top of your screen 'navbar-fixed-top'.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"><div class="container"></div></nav>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position property in the header element instead the .navbar:

```
header {
 position: fixed;
}
```